# Google Maps API limitations

Tags: google-maps

I have a vehicle tracking system and I have a flash map which can
request a map from my map server or a map from google map api.
I do not understand the limitation of map api. It says "If more than
15,000 geocode requests in a 24 hour period are received from a single
IP address..."
Does this is limited only with my server or the limit is for client
views?

Comment: Yes I saw it, so you ended up buying google maps license or you went for any other option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are asking for the quota of the free Google Maps API, but note that you cannot use the free version for vehicle tracking. Article 10.9.C of [Google Maps API Terms and Conditions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) explicitly restrict using the standard Google Maps API for fleet management and asset tracking. You would need the [Google Maps API Premier](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) to legally use Google Maps for your application.

The Premier API automatically comes with "[advanced geocoding capabilities with greater volume and speed](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html)", so the limitations of the standard API should be superseded by new quotas.

As an additional side-note, according to one [unofficial source](http://withthatsaid.com/google-maps-api-premier-follow-up-on-licensing-pricing/) (dated April 2008), the Premier API for vehicle tracking would cost USD 10,000 per year, which entitles you to track 100 vehicles. If you exceed the 100 vehicles, you would need to add USD 24 per additional vehicle per year.

Comment: Probably this system: http://212.175.126.190/fx/sd/ uses unlimited vesion :). User: demo Pwd: demo

10.9-c: "dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking, or similar enterprise applications (the Google Maps APIs can be used to track assets (such as cars, buses or other vehicles) as long as the tracking application is made available to the public without charge."

Comment: Then how come many companies are selling GPS devices and providing life time free tracking ?  using google maps.

Answer (score 4):

it's 15000 per day per IP 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_limit

And 50k per day per key : http://www.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/signup.html

Comment: Are you sure about this?
http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/cd36104df92241cf/